# JQuery to reload DIV? (Flask/Jinja2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I've searched to no avail.. I guess my question is a bit unique. I have a DIV with some content in it, that content get's brought in currently by passing the object of a SQL query into the template. That works fine, but doesn't allow me to update the content every x seconds, without refreshing the entire page. Something I don't want to do. So I wanted to know I could force JQuery to reload my DIV element? Would this also reload the code in it? Because that would force my div to update.. Here is the code.

```
<div id=content1>
    {{ set content = get_content(parm1, parm2) }} # This is a custom Jinja2 function I wrote to pull the content I need one in the template, but it only runs once.
    {% for row in content %}
    .. do stuff
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Is it possible to get JQuery to just reload that DIV with the code that is already there? If so that should fix my issue. I have thought about trying to create a call to get the content in JSON but IF possible would rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def some_view():
    name = request.args.get('name', 'Anonymous')
    if request.is_xhr:
        template_name = 'template_ajax.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'template.html'
    return render_template(template_name, name=name)
```

**template.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>Hello, {{ name }}!</div>
        <p>Some text</p>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('div').load('/?name=username');
            });        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**template_ajax.html**

```
Hello from AJAX, {{ name }}!
```

Comment: This is what I kind of ended up going with.. but a bit different.. My question is.. what is you only had $('div').load();

Would that just load the content that is in the DIV currently?

Comment: Yep, `$('div').load();` load content in the div without reload the rest of the page.